# C++ - std::enable_if for more types

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I have a function:

```
template <typename T,
  typename std::enable_if <std::is_same<T, int>::value == true>::type* = nullptr>
void test(T i)
{
   //process data
}
```

It works.

However, I need to enable this function not only for `int`, but for `float` and `const char *` as well... how to do this without writing the same method 3x times?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Like this:

```
template <typename T,
  typename std::enable_if <std::is_same<T, int         >::value ||
                           std::is_same<T, float       >::value ||
                           std::is_same<T, const char *>::value>::type* = nullptr>
void test(T i)
{
   //process data
}
```

Comment: One suggestion. Probably one can ass `remove_cv` if qualifiers shall not matter in the selection of overloading.

Comment: @YanZhou Since the parameter `i` is not passed by reference, but by value, constness and volatileness will be removed anyways. Therefore, `T` will not be cv-qualified and `remove_cv` won't do anything to the type.

Comment: How to specialize this for int, float, const char*? Process data for every type is different.

Answer (score 3):

A generic solution for C++17 ( checked on godbolt.org)

```
#include <type_traits>

template< typename U, typename ... Ts > struct belong_to
{
  // before C++17 value will have to be defined recursively on the head of Ts
  static constexpr bool value = (std::is_same< U, Ts >::value || ... );
  using type = typename std::enable_if< value, U > ::type;
};

// usage example:
template< typename T >
using testable = typename belong_to< T, int, float, const char >::type;

template< typename T > void test ( testable< T > i ) 
{
    // test process
}

int main()
{
   test< int        > ( 3 );
   test< float      > ( 3.0 );
   test< const char > ('c');
   // test< signed char >( 1 ); does not compile!!!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another generic solution is to use std::disjunction (C++17) in order to perform the logical ORs.  The allowable types are specified as template parameters in the call to your test function, or you can define a typedef for the specialization.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename... Ts, typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::disjunction<std::is_same<T, Ts>...>::value>::type* = nullptr>
void test(T i)
{
    std::cout << "test\n";
}

int main()
{
    int i = 4;
    test<int, float, const char*>(i);
    //test<float, const char*>(i); // compile fails since no int

    // or use a typedef for the specialization
    typedef void (*specialized_t)(int);
    constexpr specialized_t test2 = &test<int, float, const char*>;
    test2(i);
}
```

[run the code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2ee6964f3b9eaa8b)

Answer (score 0):

Since this is one of the first hits on Google searches, I figured I'd chime in four years later...

For C++20, it's even simpler:

```
template <typename T, 
          typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T,Type1> || std::is_same_v<T, Type2>>
```